What is the maximum size of an Aromatic Green Dwarf coconut palm?
I am thinking of planting an Aromatic Green Dwarf coconut palm (a.k.a Pandan coconut palm) because its lower height makes harvests easier. The coconut palm would be planted in a home garden in tropical lowland Southeast Asia. I am concerned that it could grow too tall as it matures. What is the maximum height of Aromatic Green Dwarf coconut palms?
I am also concerned about the crown width of this dwarf coconut palm variety, because of my garden's small land area. I do not want the fronds of the coconut palm to overhang too much over my neighbor's land, for example. What is the maximum width of the Pandan coconut palm's crown?
